# How to debug assembly?

Tags: linux, shell, assembly, gdb

I have the following assembly file `test` which I want to debug,

How can I do that?

Note I am working with x86-64 and att syntax, plus I don't have access to c code.
I want to stop after each line and being able to see the registers in a table (I remember there is such an option).

I tried:

```
gdb test
r
```

but I get:

```
Starting program:  
No executable file specified.
Use the "file" or "exec-file" command.
```

Comment: If you are looking for a full fledged debugger GDB would definitely be a great choice, however I find that most of the time it's overkill, but great nonetheless once you get the controls down. I'd recommend taking a look at the GNU Binutils package though. You can use objdump to disassemble with either the -d option for .TEXT segment or -D for all segments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running GDB *on the executable*<sup>1</sup>:
Use `start` or `starti` to set a breakpoint in main or _start respectively and run the program.

Or set breakpoints yourself with `b 12` to set a breakpoint on source line 12 (if you built with enough debug info for this to work), or `b *0x00401007` to set a breakpoint on an address you copy/pasted from `disas` output.

`layout asm` / `layout reg` puts GDB into text-UI mode with "windows" in your terminal for disassembly and registers.  (This can be a bit flaky, you sometimes need control-L to redraw the screen, and sometimes GDB crashes when your process exits although I'm not sure if that's specifically from TUI.)
Otherwise without TUI mode, `info reg` and `disas` can be useful.

See the bottom of https://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info for more asm debugging tips.

Especially **`strace ./test`** is highly useful to see the system calls your program makes, decoded into C style.  In toy programs you're playing with for your own experimentation, this basically works as an alternative to checking for error return values.

---

**Footnote 1**: You're not doing that part correctly:

> `No executable file specified.`

That means no file called `test` existed in the directory where you ran `gdb test`.

You have to assemble + link `test.S` into an executable called `test` before you can run GDB on that file.  If `ls -l test` shows it, then `gdb test` can debug it.  (And `./test` can run it.)

---

Often `gcc -no-pie foo.S` is a good choice to make debugging easier: addresses will be fixed at link time, so `objdump -drwC -Mintel test` output will match the addresses you see at run-time.  And the addresses will be numerically smaller, so it's easier to visually spot a code (.text) address vs. .rodata (modern `ld` puts it in a separate page so it can avoid exec permission) vs. .data / .bss.

Either way, stack addresses are still easy to distinguish from code either way, 0x555... or `0x0000...XXXXXX` is in the executable, `0x7fffff...` is in the stack, other addresses from mmap are randomized.  (But libc also gets mapped to a high address near the stack, with or without PIE.)

(Or if you're writing `_start` instead of `main`, `gcc -nostdlib -static foo.S` implies `-no-pie`)